# sending data failed due to strange characters in HTTP headers

Tags: c

I used the following code to create the hTTP Headers and send it to the server. However, when it is received, it contains strange characters.

```
 const char http_post_format[]=
 {
  "POST /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n\
  Host: %s\r\n\
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\
  Content-Length:%s\r\n\r\n\
  %s\r\n"
 };
```

The code snippet is as below:

```
 int client_fd = -1;
 int len =- 1;
 char *ipstr=(char*)malloc(16);
 struct sockaddr_t addr;
 char *content_length=(char*)malloc(20);
 char *httpRequest = (char*)malloc(556);

 // cs_log("Free memory has %d bytes", MicoGetMemoryInfo()->free_memory) ;
 gethostbyname(http_host, (uint8_t *)ipstr, 16);
 cs_log("server address: host:%s, ip: %s", http_host, ipstr);

 client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 addr.s_ip = inet_addr(ipstr);
 addr.s_port = http_port;
 connect(client_fd, &addr, sizeof(addr));

 Int2Str((uint8_t*)content_length, strlen(str_args));

 cs_log("content_length%s\n ",content_length);

 sprintf(httpRequest, http_post_format,
      http_post_url,
      http_host,
      content_length,
      str_args);

 len=write(client_fd,(uint8_t *)httpRequest, strlen(httpRequest));
 if(len == -1){
   memset(httpRequest,0,556);
 }
 cs_log("len%d\n%s\n ",len,httpRequest);

 free(httpRequest);
 httpRequest = NULL;
 close(client_fd);
 free(content_length);
 content_length=NULL;
 free(ipstr);
 ipstr =NULL;
```

The expected http headers which can be parsed are as below:

```
POST /sensor/sensorinfo HTTP/1.1 
Host: 192.168.199.218
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length:240

info={ "WIFI_INFO": { "WIFI": { "connected": "1", "strength": "80", "ip": "192.168.199.131", "mac": "d0bae4075913", "ssid": "chaosuan" } }, "DHT11_INFO": { "DHT": { "T": "28", "H": "43" } }, "DSM501A_INFO": { "DSM501A": { "VALUE": "0" } } }
```

The actual data received contains some strange characters in Content-Length.

```
POST /sensor/sensorinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.199.218
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length:240棍*橪馭嶲誳3

info={ "WIFI_INFO": { "WIFI": { "connected": "1", "strength": "74", "ip": "192.168.199.131", "mac": "d0bae4075913", "ssid": "chaosuan" } }, "DHT11_INFO": { "DHT": { "T": "28", "H": "43" } }, "DSM501A_INFO": { "DSM501A": { "VALUE": "0" } } }
```

Here is the Int2Str function

```
 void Int2Str(uint8_t* str, int32_t intnum)
 {
 uint32_t i, Div = 1000000000, j = 0, Status = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
   str[j++] = (intnum / Div) + 48;

   intnum = intnum % Div;
   Div /= 10;
   if ((str[j-1] == '0') & (Status == 0))
   {
    j  = 0;
   }
   else
  {
    Status++;
  }
 } 
 }
```

Comment: Looks like a forgotten NUL terminator. There is probably a `str[j] = 0` missing somewhere at the end of the `int2Str` function.

Comment: Also, why not just make `content_length` an int to begin with and use %d format spec?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to NUL terminate your string in `Int2Str`:

The end of this function should look like this:

```
   ...
   {
     Status++;
   }
  } 

  str[j] = 0;  // <<< add this
}
```

Disclaimer: untested code, there may be more issues.

By the way, why did you write `Int2Str`? The [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) or the more standard [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) function do the same job.

You even could have used directly `sprintf` with the `%d` format specifier which es even simpler.

**Side note**

`+ 48` is bad. Rather write `+ '0'`, so nobody has to guess that 48 it the ASCII code for the '0' character.

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard. `sprintf` would do the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is in 0-terminator in Int2Str. It does not exist in the code provided and should be inserted after the string has been filled.

But there are a number of minor problems, which potentially may influence the execution.
1) No connect() result checking (server might be not found);
2) No malloc() result checking (this is a critical flaw, in certain circumstances it could lead to the unwanted arbitrary code execution).